# PHP XPath select element based on attribute value

Tags: php, parsing, xpath, domdocument

Hey guys so I have a problem here. I want to select an element based on what is in one of its attributes using XPath in PHP. Here's what I mean.

```
<a href="/example.php?id=6&q=h">Link1</a>
<a href="/example.php?id=4&q=s">Link1</a>
<a href="/example.php?id=3&q=d">Link1</a>
<a href="/example.php?id=9&q=h">Link1</a>
<a href="/example.php?id=7&q=f">Link1</a>
<a href="/example.php?id=8&q=h">Link1</a>
```

So, let's pretend that this is a full page with 100's of links. I want to only extract those that have q=h. I know that I could loop through all of the a tags then use an if statement to see if q=h exists. However, that does not seem very efficient when there are hundreds of links. Thanks

Comment: It's not a foolproof solution, but you could do [this](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/b5e9182f6dde71a550affe71cbcfd958).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally do this

```
<?php

$htmlC = '<a href="/example.php?id=6&q=h">Link1</a>
<a href="/example.php?id=4&q=s">Link1</a>
<a href="/example.php?id=3&q=d">Link1</a>
<a href="/example.php?id=9&q=h">Link1</a>
<a href="/example.php?id=7&q=f">Link1</a>
<a href="/example.php?id=8&q=h">Link1</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($htmlC);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$query = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href, 'q=h')]");

foreach($query as $link){
//do what you need
}

?>
```